# Public Event/Contribution Pages Not Showing

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, joomla, contribution-page, forms

I have created an event and I have set permissions for public access based on the following from the permissions guide :

> Viewing event info and registering for events¶
>
> If **view event info** and **register for events** are enabled (*I
> HAVE THESE ENABLED*) for the anonymous and authenticated roles then
> all visitors to your site will be able to register for any event.

I made a new hidden menu item which is an Event Registration Form and selected the event. Event date and registration date are set earlier than today. The form should be appearing here: https://www.heartgalleryofbroward.org/test-event-reg
(NOTE: The Live URL works from within the event. I tried using this URL as a menu type - URL and just get a 404 component not found).

Can someone assist? I tried looking around in stack exchange but cannot find anything other than checking permissions.

UPDATE: I also have setup a contribution form which is also not displaying. https://www.heartgalleryofbroward.org/test-contribution

Updating as well with some screenshots of public permissions:

[image: CiviEvent Permissions]

[image: CiviContribute Permissions]

[image: Other Permissions]

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Here is the screenshot of settings for menu items as CiviCRM menu settings in Joomla. These seem to be set correctly, but no form is showing.

[image]

[image]

And this is the live link I am talking about. I go to manage events, event links for our TruHearts event, live link: https://www.heartgalleryofbroward.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=3

And for Contribution pages I click links for general donation and get this: https://www.heartgalleryofbroward.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

Both live links will show someone the form in incognito mode/anonymous user. but I cannot actually get these forms to work on their own on the website through menu items.

UPDATE 2/24/24:

I confirmed that the template in use has a component section for the main body.

[image]

Comment: When you say "The Live URL works from within the event", do you mean you can register by visiting that url? It's not clear what you're trying to do - embed the civi registration page inside another page?

Comment: @Demerit I added more screenshots/clarification on what live links work, and how I am trying to get them into the website. The CiviCRM install is within our actually joomla install for our website so same system.

Comment: Ok I don't know enough about joomla and how menu items are supposed to work, or what the view=Events or layout=register mean, but it could be that the id=3 is not in the right place. It should be part of the "civi" url (e.g. at the end of the url).

Comment: Yea I was wondering about that so I even did a menu type of URL and used the live link there, but get an error page

Comment: Hi, whats the Joomla version you're using? If its v4, can you try applying this patch https://gist.github.com/jitendrapurohit/8db52cca43bb899c14c65704e51696b0 in case it fixes the issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

I see you're using a Joomshaper Helix template. Does the template style assigned to your two menu items include a Joomla "Component" area?

Are you using any custom URL rewrite rules? Have you tried the Civi menu items with friendly URLs turned off?

Are you using any firewall extension like Akeeba Admin Tools that might be blocking any of the Civi components?

Comment: How do I check about the template having a component area? If you mean, if I go to template styles and there is anything related to components, there is nothing that I can find.


For custom URL writing. Yes, it is on. I tried turning of Friendly URL and I got a 404 error page instead of just a page with the template but no form/body.


For firewall extensions I have none added except for one I added in CiviCRM itself which was required by an extension to download Stripe as a payment processor.

Comment: To check the template having a component area:  go to template styles, and find the style that your menu items are using.  Open that style and click on the "Layout" tab.  See if that layout includes a Main Body section, and if that Main Body section includes a "Component" column.

As to which style is being applied to your menu items:  it will most likely be your default style, unless you have assigned the menu items under an "Assignment" tab in one of the non-default styles.

Comment: I did confirm that component is on/works. After checking something though I realized there were two htaccess files and one was old and the new wasn't names correctly. When I fixed this I discovered I could make the pages work publically IF they were on the main menu, OR if we used a custom redirect if I want it hidden. BUT if I make an actual hidden page, it will not show. So it appears to be something wrong with how re-write handles hidden URLS that are alias based

Comment: Sounds like progress! :-)

Comment: Are you using the default Joomla htaccess rules, or do you have custom rules set up?  I also manage several Joomla/Civi installs, and Civi menu items in hidden menus work just fine -- so I'm pretty sure it's not a Civi-specific issue.

Comment: I have the .htaccess file that came with the joomla install. I am finding whacky behavior in general now that I am also tweaking CSS code for CiviCRM.  I will edit/make some changes, then the home page acts funky. And the only way to fix is to rename the .htaccess file by adding a 2 or something at the end. Refresh. Then put it back to .htaccess again and all is ok. So something really wonky is happening and I agree probably a joomla reason not Civi. Should I perhaps move this to a different stack exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure jQuery is loading on your site.

[image]

SPPagebuilder resources are not loading correctly.

[image]

The payment/donation popup is not loading its contents.

[image]

There seems to be a js/jQuery issue on your site.

You can use a menu-item to display the event registration form on your site.
**You can NOT use a custom SEO-link (menu-item type URL) to display the respective form.**

I'd suggest to work with the redirection component of joomla and redirect URL/short-link to the URL/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task...